# How to deal with message wrapper when using JSON/Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am trying to consume a JSON based service that uses a wrapper around its responses.  The wrapper looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "some message",
            "code": "possibly some error code"
        }
    ],
    "result": [],
    "metadata": {
        "limit": 100,
        "offset": 0,
        "total": 5
    }
}
```

The "result" may contain an object or an array of objects.  As an example, if I was calling an "apple" service, I would get either an apple object or array of apple objects within the result.  Likewise, if I were calling an "orange" service, I would get either an orange object or array of orange objects within the result.

The question is, how can I deserialize this using Jackson?

Thanks,

Joe